# Access a file outside of the project directory in visual studio (.aspx)

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, html5-video

**I have created a project that is located here:** `C:\Dev\Collection\Project\Mobile\`.

**The web page I am working on is located here:** 
`C:\Dev\Collection\Project\Mobile\WebForms`.

**I want to gain access to a video file that is outside of the project directory, it is located here:** `C:\Dev\Collection\Project\Documents\video.mp4`.

The Mobile folder represents my project folder. When I open the solution file, the Mobile folder and it's sub directories are displayed. The documents folder is outside the actual project folder.

**This is the code I'm using:**

```
<video style='border: 5px solid;' width="450" height="300" controls>
    <source src="../../Documents/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    Unable to play video.
</video>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I access the video which is outside my project directory?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188850/discussion-on-question-by-panic-access-a-file-outside-of-the-project-directory-i).